# How to deploy a contract on your chain

Tags: smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, pallet-contracts

Hi i have cloned the `node-template` and also added the pallet-contract in it, now i want to know that how can i deploy a smart contract on my chain i have also deployed it on `EC2` instance but i want to know how can i deploy and write smart contract on my chain network. Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: can you explain more related that issue.Do you want to add contract into your node template runtime or something else.

Comment: yes you got it right contract on node template

Answer (score 0):

If you have your network with the pallet contracts in it running you can already deploy smart contracts.

You have two options to deploy the Smart Contract, see the ink! docs [Deploy your Contract](https://use.ink/getting-started/deploy-your-contract/).

1. Using the tool [cargo-contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract), you can follow the Substrate Docs: [Deploy and test the smart contract](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/develop-a-smart-contract/#deploy-and-test-the-smart-contract)
2. Using the UI: https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ you just need to change and use your local node.